# Can I ask General Robotics Questions?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this website intended to only answer ROS specific questions? Or can we also ask general robotics questions that we have while running our ROS systems although it's not particularly about ROS?

The only other place I can think of asking such questions is Robotics Stack Exchange but I feel like the community here is a great help as well.

Also, maybe a meta page for ROS answers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195070/can-i-ask-general-robotics-questions?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-10-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Robotics StackExchange was created for exactly the purpose you ask about. If there is any ROS component to your question at all, then by all means, ROS Answers is an appropriate venue, but if not, Robotics StackExchange would be better. Additionally, the [ROS Support Guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29) say that ROS Answers is not for "general debugging/programming questions not specific to ROS."

The only way to build a good community at Robotics StackExchange is to ask and answer questions there!

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6